# CoreData multiple persistent store coordinator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I can't fully grasp the CoreData terms.

I have created two `.xcdatamodeld` files for two conceptually separate dataset.

One is about caching static data which I downloaded from the net.
One is about temporary posts which a user has written but not submitted to the server yet.

These two dataset doesn't need to know each other at all.

I want a setup that would give me least headache when I try to update either one.

Would I need two separate `persistent store coordinator`? or two separate `persistent store`? and what does that mean anyway?

** Edit

I guess Mundi suggests something like the following.

```
1 coordinator --- store1 --- model1
      \
       \
         ----- store2 --- model2
```

How can I achieve that in code?

I have the following codes (copied from tutorial sites) and the structure is more or like

```
psc --- model1
  \
   \
     --- store1
```

rather than

```
psc --- model1 --- store1
```

My existing code looks like..

```
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"CachedURLResponse" withExtension:@"momd"];

_managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

_persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.sqlite"];
NSError *error = nil;
[_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]
```

How do I achieve the separate stores for models in one coordinator?

I could live with separate tables for each model in RDMS world. I could later update the table definition, and migrate data just as easily as I had two separate databases.

I'm not sure how easy it would be to update different tables(models) in one database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually a persistent store is analogous to a database; it's a place to store data which conforms to some schema. A persistent store coordinator manages reads and writes to one or more persistent stores.

How you want to structure your CoreData stack probably depends on how you want to query the data.

If these two data sets are completely distinct you might give each one it's own store and coordinator and managed object context(s). However in that case you won't be able to construct a query (via a `NSFetchRequest`) for "all posts both saved or unsaved" and you might have to do some extra work to keep track of when a post moves from one state to the other to make sure you don't store a version of the same post in both stores.

If you do need to query across both sets of data then you'd need a single coordinator which can manage which entities are saved in each store. That requires you to do some work in the coordinator but might allow the rest of the app to be ignorant of the mechanics of these persistent stores.

You'll need to decide which path would be easier for you to work with and maintain.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than going into the architectural complexities of setting up different store coordinators and contexts, I would simply create two different stores and different entities to make sure the two data sets do not interfere with each other.

This would satisfy your requirement of "least headache" while letting you use plain vanilla code.

The basic procedure for multiple stores and models is as follows:

- in the models, include your entities in a "Configuration", use different names for the two stores.
- when setting up the Core Data stack, merge the models
- rather than adding just one persistent store to the coordinator with configuration as `nil`, add two stores with the respective configuration names.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Although I am having trouble in translating your idea to code.. I've edited the question, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a merged model, you can do it in code, without changing your model files.

Assuming two models, "CachedURLResponse" and "TemporaryPosts" where you want a separate store that contains all entities in each model, you can do something like this.

```
- (NSString*)configurationForModelNamed:(NSString*)modelName {
    return [modelName stringByAppendingString:@".config"];
}

- (NSURL*)URLForModelNamed:(NSString*)modelName {
    NSString *name = [modelName stringByAppendingString:@".sqlite"];
    return [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:name];
}

- (NSManagedObjectModel*)mergedModelForModelNames:(NSArray*)modelNames {
    NSMutableArray *models = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString * name in modelNames) {
        NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:name withExtension:@"momd"];
        NSManagedObjectModel *model = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
        [model setEntities:model.entities forConfiguration:[self configurationForModelNamed:name]];
        [models addObject:model];
    }
    return [NSManagedObjectModel modelByMergingModels:models];
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator*)pscForModelNames:(NSArray*)modelNames {
    NSManagedObjectModel *model = [self mergedModelForModelNames:modelNames];
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:model];
    for (NSString *name in modelNames) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                               configuration:[self configurationForModelNamed:name]
                                         URL:[self URLForModelNamed:name]
                                     options:nil
                                       error:&error]) {
            // Handle error...
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you could create the PSC with whatever momd models you want...

```
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [self pscForModelNames:@[@"CachedURLResponse", @"TemporaryPosts"]];
```